# Add custom filters to Joomla! default search?

Tags: search, filter, joomla1.7

this is my first time posting a question here.
I'm trying to add some custom filters to the Joomla! default search, but I just add the custom filters to the html.
How do I make it work?

Answer (score 0):

First thing you are going to have to look at is the default search component and see if the model has any way of accounting for various query variables, specifically the ones you want to use to filter your results. For example, if you want to limit searches to a couple of categories, you need to see if you can pass some category IDs to the model and it would include them in the 'where' clause when it builds the SQL query. If it does, then all you need to do is to create a custom search form that includes the filters you would like to use.

If it doesn't, then it gets a little trickier. I would highly recommend not hacking the core, so you would need to replicate the search component, then rename it and install it as a new component once you have made the necessary changes to the model.

It would also be advisable to see if anyone else has already written an extension that would accomplish the same task. I would stick with extensions that have made it in to the JED - http://extensions.joomla.org/

Comment: Thank you Brent, I've added the form fields, but I cannot get the varibables in the model. I just added some filters in the docman search, but in the Joomla default search doesn't look that easy.

Comment: Unfortunately it isn't that easy. Anything you want to filter has to be included in the core model otherwise you will have to create your own component. The good news is that you can simply copy the core component and rename it, then add in the new code there.